# Issue with contents of multiple pickerView's iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to place two picker views in one view controller. I have implemented both `pickerView:viewForRow:` and `pickerView:titleForRow:`. These functions use tags to differentiate between pickers. My problem is that only one of them will be effective. So, because I want views in one and text in the other, but it will be the case that either both get views or both get text. Can I use the `pickerView:titleForRow:` function on one and `pickerView:viewForRow:` for the other?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use both `pickerView:viewForRow` and `pickerView:titleForRow` at the same time in the same `UIPickerViewDelegate`.  While `pickerView:titleForRow` returns `String?`, giving the option of returning nil, `pickerView:viewForRow` does not return an optional; if you implement this function then it must return a view.

This leaves you with two options:

1. Create a suitable view for your 'string' picker - A UILabel, for example, and return it from `pickerView:viewForRow`
2. Create a separate object to serve as the delegate for one of the picker views